# Spring Routing-source and connection pooling

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling

I am using spring Routing data source as explained here and things works well. Now, I want to add connection pooling (Apache DBCP). I changed the basic data source to the connection pool data source. well, It does not work.

On the server start-up I see that connection pooling is happening and I can debug Apache's code, but then, when I am trying to access the DB through my code, I go to the routing data source, and from there to the DriverManager class to get a connection - completely ignoring Apache's code.

```xml
<bean id="catalogDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pwd}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis"><value>300000</value></property> 
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis"><value>60000</value></property> 
</bean>

<bean id="dsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="catalogDataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="dsConnectionFactory"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><ref bean="pool"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><value>false</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value>true</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="poolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="pool"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="routingDataSource" class="something that derived from RoutingDataSource">
   <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="pooledDS"/>
   <property name="targetDataSources">
   <map key-type="java.lang.Integer">
  </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Can you help me please - what did I do wrong?